# Automation for Mobile Web Site by Testcomplete 10

Tags: testing, testcomplete

I am trying to automate mobile web site, so i am using virtual browser in Testcomplete 10. But i couldnot able to map any child object from parent.
I can take main page screenshot only. Below steps i had done,

1) opend www.google.com by using virtual browser with Apple ipad or any other

2) took screenshot for main page, Name Mapping path : Aliases.browser.BrowserWindow.Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND

3) Trying to map Google search textbox, but could not map that child objects from parent("Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND").

Can any one confirm possible solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're using Chrome 34?

You need TestComplete 10.10 with the [Chrome 33 patch](http://support.smartbear.com/downloads/testcomplete/chrome-patches/) (it works for Chrome 34, too).

Also, make sure that the TestComplete extension version in `chrome://extensions` is 10.10.xxx; otherwise uninstall and reinstall both Chrome and TestComplete as [explained here](http://smartbear.com/forums/f75/t88650/using-chrome-34-for-web-testing/).